# html content into another html on navigation bar click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all I'm totally new in webprograming, only familiar with css and html, and my knowledge is not enough to solve this...
So I'm trying to a make a simple website, with a header(logo, title etc) navigation bar, body and footer... Now on the navigation bar if the user clicks on let's say the "prices" menu, I want it to open under the nav bar and change the content from an external html file to fill the div there but instead it creates another scrollbar, cuz the content is longer than the home page's or something like that.
I used this code to do it:

```
   <script>
function changingstuff4() {
     document.getElementById("changingstuff").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="prices.html" style="position: absolute; height:100%; width:100%;"></object>';
}
</script>
```

With this code the width fills the div, but height is only 200-300 px... If I use height: 1500px; it works without problem but if I add another row of text, It will be longer than 1500px so it creats another scrollbar again...

Tried a lot of solution found here, but none of it worked for me... Even if you can give me hints where to look for the problem will be much appreciated, and hope everything is understandable.

Best example for what I want to do is this page
In the top there is a navigation bar.
If I click on "questions" "developer jobs" etc it opens new content without changing the top and the footer, only the content in middle.

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/cb5f4a16/

Comment: If you can create the Plunker or JSFiddle then would be very useful to resolve the issue.

Comment: Oh I forgot that: https://jsfiddle.net/cb5f4a16/
the external html is the same, just without the footer and head parts